# Decimal Datatype Support in Avro Schema and Generated Files

Tags: java, avro

This question concerns Avro version 1.8.1.

We have the following field in our AVRO schema:

```
"name" : "sale_price", 
"type" : ["bytes", "null"], 
"logicalType": "decimal", 
"precision": 18, 
"scale": 17,
```

As you can see, the logicalType of the field has been defined as `decimal`.

But when we use the `avro-maven-plugin`, it does not generate the correct data type within the generated Java source files.
Instead it generates, `java.nio.ByteBuffer`. 
How would you have the correct data type generated within the Java files?

This is our plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <stringType>String</stringType>
        <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: [`enableDecimalLogicalType`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1847) was introduced in Avro 1.8.2 (not yet released).

Comment: What's the expected correct data type? Are you expecting the logicalType as the correct data type?

Answer (score 9):

If you want BigDecimal you need to use version 1.8.2 and add `enableDecimalLogicalType` parameter with `true` value to your pom file:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
<artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-avro-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>schema</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/generated-sources/main/java/</outputDirectory>
            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

For more info, check this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1847

Answer (score 4):

I had to do the Following. (Since i could not find any documentation on how to set decimal value, it might help others)

1. **Define decimal field**

   ```
    {
    "namespace": "com.billionDollarCompany",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "AverageObject",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "average",
        "type": {
          "type": "bytes",
          "logicalType": "decimal",
          "precision": 4,
          "scale": 2
        }
      }
    ]
   }
   ```
2. Convert Decimal number of byteBuffer

   ```
    public static ByteBuffer ByteBuffer(Schema classSchema, String fieldName, double value)
    {
        LogicalType type = classSchema.getField(fieldName).schema().getLogicalType();
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(value, MathContext.DECIMAL32).setScale(((LogicalTypes.Decimal) type).getScale(), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bigDecimal.unscaledValue().toByteArray());
    }
   ```

   **What is Scale and precision?**

   > Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

Comment: I could not find anything on the docs regarding what precision refers to, thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

As the [Avro docs](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Logical+Types) explain,

> Language implementations must ignore unknown logical types when reading, and should use the underlying Avro type.
>
> A [decimal logical type](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Decimal) annotates Avro bytes or fixed types.

Hence in the generated Java files, the decimal logical type is represented in the underlying Avro type bytes, i.e., `java.nio.ByteBuffer`